# Passing Large(ish) Byte Array to WCF Service Fails with All Max Attributes Maxed Out

Tags: arrays, wcf

I'm calling a method in a WCF service and passing a DTO with a property of type byte[] that contains the contents of a file. This works fine until the file gets up to about 3 MB, at which point it fails. All the information I've been able to find talks about setting configuration attributes to larger values but I have already maxed everything out. This is from my web ste config file:

```
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="dxWsBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="None"  >
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
        <message establishSecurityContext="false" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="UserContextClientBehavior">
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
      <UserContextBehaviorExtension />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

and this is from my web service config file:

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="DefaultBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True"/>
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="ErrorLoggerBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True"/>
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
      <ErrorLogger logName="DXWcfErrorLog" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="dxWsBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="None"  >
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
        <message establishSecurityContext="false" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Note that it is not my intention to use those maximum values in production but I was trying everything to get this to work.

When a request fails I don't see anything in my web service. I tried this in both config files:

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <trace autoflush="true">
    <listeners>
    </listeners>
  </trace>
  <sources>
    <source name="System.ServiceModel"
            switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
            propagateActivity="true">
      <listeners>
        <add name="sdt"
             type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
             initializeData= "WcfDetailTrace.svclog" />
      </listeners>
    </source>
  </sources>
</system.diagnostics>
```

but when I opened the web service log file there was no sign of the failed request at all.  The web site log file showed me what I already knew.  Here's the information I get on the client side, i.e. the web site:

```
2012-09-25 12:26:46,273 ERROR Unexpected exception occurred
System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to http://localhost:52114/DocumentService.svc. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
at System.Net.PooledStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
at System.Net.Connection.SyncRead(HttpWebRequest request, Boolean userRetrievedStream, Boolean probeRead)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Server stack trace:
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]:
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
at SI.Doh.Aon.Service.Interface.IServiceBase`1.AddEntity(TDto dto)
at SI.Doh.Aon.Web.Controllers.DocumentUploaderController.Upload(DocumentEditModel model, HttpPostedFileBase FileName) in C:\SVN Source\Department_Of_Health\Area_Of_Need\src\SI.Doh.Aon.Web\Controllers\DocumentUploaderController.cs:line 142
at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.c__DisplayClass15.
  b__12()
  at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
  at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.c__DisplayClass15.c__DisplayClass17.
    b__14()
    at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
    at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
    at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore()
    at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
    at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
    at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.c__DisplayClass6.c__DisplayClassb.
      b__5()
      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.c__DisplayClass1.
        b__0()
        at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.c__DisplayClass8`1.
          b__7(IAsyncResult _)
          at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
          at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.c__DisplayClasse.
            b__d()
            at System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.b__0(Action f)
   at System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is also a maxRequestLength inside the httpRuntime attribute.

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097151" />
</system.web>
```

Comment: That was indeed the max that I had missed. I don't recall having seen that particular attribute mentioned in the several other questions I've seen on a similar topic so that thank you very much Cybermaxs.