# WCF Service error "Maximum message size quota for incoming message as been exceeded"

Tags: vb.net, web-services, wcf, wcf-binding

I have a WCF Service library project who request a large recordset from a database and returns it. This error pop everytime in the WCF Test Client. I changed the MaxReceivedMessageSize to a large value but it doesn't seem to take it. Here the Web.Config

```
 <client>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:8000/SAPIntranet" binding="basicHttpBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="Binding_SAPIntranet" contract="SAPIntranet"
    name="SAPIntranet" kind="" endpointConfiguration="" />
</client>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="Binding_SAPIntranet" openTimeout="00:02:00" maxBufferPoolSize="20000000"
      maxBufferSize="20000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Error message always gives the default value (65535). 
I guess there is something I'm doing wrong, but can't figure it out.

Thanks for your time and help

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12578291/passing-largeish-byte-array-to-wcf-service-fails-with-all-max-attributes-maxed) question of mine may be of some help.

Answer (score 0):

`MaxReceivedMessageSize` setting takes effect on the server-side, we should apply the binding configuration on the service endpoint. The above configuration applies only to the client service endpoint. Please refer to the below service configuration.

```
  <services>
    <service name="WcfService1.Service1">
      <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="mybinding" contract="WcfService1.IService1">
      </endpoint>
      <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"></endpoint>
    </service>
  </services>
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="mybinding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
          maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" />
      </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
```

Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I already tried this and it doesn't work either, still have the same error message.

Comment: I would like to know the complete configuration on the server-side, would you mind posting it? Besides, your configuration appears to me that is only applied to the client-side, nor the server-side.